# Using mutate_at, starts_with and case_when with list to change values of multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a quick question. I want to change multiple column values at once (basically change numeric values to strings in a questionnaire). I found a way to do it using `mutate_at` and `case_when`. The example used `funs`, which I was told to replace by list, however, it does not work. I'm not sure if I'm using `list()` incorrectly, or if something else is going wrong. Here's an example that produces the same error as my data:

```
library(tidyverse)

q11_1 <- sample(rep(c(1:4), 10))
q11_2 <- sample(rep(c(1:4), 10))
q12_1 <- sample(rep(c(1:4), 10))
q12_2 <- sample(rep(c(1:4), 10))
df <- data.frame(q11_1, q11_2, q12_1, q12_2)

df %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(starts_with('q11')), 
    list(case_when(
      . == 1 ~ "Yes", 
      . == 2 ~ "No", 
      . == 3 ~ "Maybe", 
      . == 4 ~ "Don't know"
    ))
  )
```

To clarify: I have a dataset with q11_1, q11_2 ... etc. and I want to change the values for all vars that start with q11 (which are all numeric). The error I get is:

```
Error in get(.x, .env, mode = "function") : first argument has length > 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't give an expected output, but I believe this is what you want.

We should use `across()` now like this, as `mutate_at` is deprecated. `across` takes two arguments; one to select the columns and the second is the function which should be applied to those columns. Also, no need to wrap the `case_when` statement in `list`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    across(starts_with('q11'), 
    function(x) case_when(
      x == 1 ~ "Yes", 
      x == 2 ~ "No", 
      x == 3 ~ "Maybe", 
      x == 4 ~ "Don't know"
    )
  )
)
```

```
        q11_1      q11_2 q12_1 q12_2
1          No         No     4     1
2          No        Yes     4     2
3         Yes Don't know     1     2
4  Don't know Don't know     1     2
5  Don't know        Yes     3     1
6          No      Maybe     4     1
7         Yes         No     3     3
8  Don't know      Maybe     3     3
9       Maybe      Maybe     3     4
10 Don't know Don't know     4     1
11      Maybe         No     1     2
12      Maybe      Maybe     1     2
13      Maybe Don't know     4     1
14        Yes         No     3     4
15 Don't know        Yes     2     3
16      Maybe         No     3     4
17        Yes         No     4     1
18        Yes Don't know     3     4
19      Maybe         No     3     2
20      Maybe      Maybe     1     3
21        Yes      Maybe     2     2
22        Yes      Maybe     1     3
23 Don't know      Maybe     1     2
24      Maybe        Yes     2     4
25         No        Yes     1     3
```